# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2483: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

I am parsing a csv file and i am getting the below error

```
import os
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
demo_data = defaultdict(list)

if os.path.exists("infoed_daily _file.csv"):
    f = open("infoed_daily _file.csv", "rt")
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    line_no = 0
    for line in csv_reader:
    line_no +=1
    print(line,line_no)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2483: character maps to 
<undefined>
```

Please advise.

Thanks..
-Prasanna.K

Comment: maybe file uses encoding different then `utf-8` - ie `latin-1`, `cp1250` - and you may have to use it in `open()`. And you could check in Google what char may have code `0x81` and in which encoding it can be.

Comment: when I run `b'\x81'.decode('Latin1')` or `b'\x81'.decode('Latin2')` or `b'\x81'.decode('iso8859')` or `b'\x81'.decode('iso8859-2')` then it runs without error - so your file can be in some of these encodings (or similar encoding) and you have to use it `open(..., encoding='Latin1')`

Comment: Thanks all. I used `encoding="latin-1"`  it worked well. thanks so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 55: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39755301/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x81-in-position-55-chara)

Answer (score 5):

Error may means you have file in encoding different then `UTF-8` which (probably in most systems) is used as default in `open()`

When I run

```
 b'\x81'.decode('Latin1') 
 b'\x81'.decode('Latin2') 
 b'\x81'.decode('iso8859') 
 b'\x81'.decode('iso8859-2')
```

then it runs without error - so your file can be in some of these encodings (or similar encoding) and you have to use it

```
 open(..., encoding='Latin1')
```

or similar.

List of other encodings: [codecs: standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Answer (score -1):

```
f=open("myfile1.txt",'r')
print(f.read())
```

Well, for the above code I got an error as:
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 637: character maps to 
so i tried changing the name of the file extension and it worked.
Happy Coding
Thanks!
Vani

Answer (score -1):

you can use '

```
with open ('filename.txt','r') as f:
      f.write(content)
```

The good thing is that it automatically closes the file after work is done.

Comment: This snippet does not fix possible encoding issues OP has